# Declaring Encryption in a ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, encryption

Im receiving the following error

"Name 'Encryption' is not declared."

On Line

If reader_login("password").ToString() = Encryption.Rijndael.Encrypt(Password, "SHA1", 2, 256) Then

Locally it is fine just seeing this error now on my development machine.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by "locally it is fine just seeing this error now on my development machine"?  Normally "local" does refer to one's development machine.

Comment: Ok..sorry for the typo I meant on the production server im seeing the above error.

Comment: What is your `Encryption` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to copy a DLL or a file in `App_Code` to the server.

Comment: I dont actually have an Encryption class but I see there is a dll in the bin folder EncDec.dll which I believe holds this class. Could it be an issue reading this dll ?

Comment: Copy that DLL to the `bin` folder in the server.

Comment: In Visual Studio, right-click on `Rijndael` and click `Go to Definition` to find out where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find out where the Encryption class is located in your development machine?  If it's a 3rd party component that's installed in the GAC, you'll need to install that component on the server too, or if possible copy its assembly (.dll) to the bin folder of your application on the production server.